# How can i make app wait to get all data from module that get data from firestore before run in react-native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I have DATA from petData.js that get data from firestore

```
import firebase from '../fb';
import 'firebase/firestore';
const DATA = [];
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('pets')
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      DATA.push(doc.data());
    });
  });

module.exports = DATA;
```

And Popular.js to wait for data before running

```
import DATA from '../data/petData';
class Popular extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={item => {
            return (
              <PetItem
                navigation={this.props.screenProps}
                source={item.item.source}
                name={item.item.name}
                info={item.item.info}
                price={item.item.price}
              />
            );
          }}></FlatList>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If i run before getting all data it become like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4mZj.png)

Comment: Why u get data and set it as module?

Comment: Am i doing wrong? cause i still can get DATA after reload many time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, u should take a look to lifecycle methods in react, in your case the render method it's run the first one and every time u set a state, so u should get the data in didMount method that's run after ur component mounted

So expected behavior at first time 
Data is null/undefined/empty so the flatlist will not appear

So u should put a get data function inside a componentDidMount()

```
//Popular.js
import firebase from '../fb';
import 'firebase/firestore';

class Popular extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: [], 
    loading:true
  }
}
ComponentDidMount(){
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('pets')
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      //DATA.push(doc.data());
      this.setState({data:doc.data(), loading:false})
    });
  });
}
render() {
    //make a loading component that appears if the data is empty 
   If(this.state.loading){
      return(
        <ActivityIndecator size="large" />
      )else{
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={item => {
            return (
              <PetItem
                navigation={this.props.screenProps}
                source={item.item.source}
                name={item.item.name}
                info={item.item.info}
                price={item.item.price}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: i am doing this, but got error code 500:
--petData.js--
export const getData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DATA = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('pets')
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          DATA.push(doc.data());
        });
        console.log('DATA:', DATA);
        resolve(DATA);
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};

Comment: and Popular.js: 
componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(response => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        DATA: response,
      });
    });
  }
  state = {
    loading: true,
    DATA: [],
  };

Comment: I think u have a typo as u see in screenshot u have a "dns" word in getData.js